# Yii select2 - returned data cannot be selected

Tags: yii, jsonp, jquery-select2

I have been looking into select2 and yii and have managed to load data via json request/response.

The issue I'm faced with is when I try to select an entry of the returned data, I can not.

Where am I going wrong ? The data returnd by the action is json formatted as CustomerCode and Name

Widget code in form

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2', array(  
    'asDropDownList' => false,  
    'name' => 'CustomerCode',  
    'options' => array(     
        'placeholder' => 'Type a Customer Code',  
                'minimumInputLength' => '2',  
        'width' => '40%',  
                'ajax' => array(  
                                //'url'=> 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json',  
                                'url'=> Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/customer/SearchCustomer',  
                            'dataType' => 'jsonp',  
                            'data' => 'js: function (term,page) {  
                                        return {  
                                        term: term, // Add all the query string elements here seperated by ,  
                                        page_limit: 10,  
                                               };  
                                                             }',        
                            'results' => 'js: function (data,page) {return {results: data};}',  
                            ),  
            'formatResult'    => 'js:function(data){  
                                var markup = data.CustomerCode + " - ";  
                                markup += data.Name;  
                                return markup;  
                            }',
            'formatSelection' => 'js: function(data) {  
                                return data.CustomerCode;  
                            }',  

    )));
```

code snipped from controller action SearchCustomer

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
$this->renderJSON(Customer::model()->searchByCustomer($term));
```

renderJSON function from base controller class

```
   protected function renderJSON($data)
   {
       header('Content-type: application/json');
       echo $_GET['callback'] . "(";
       echo CJSON::encode($data);
       echo ")";


       foreach (Yii::app()->log->routes as $route) {
           if($route instanceof CWebLogRoute) {
               $route->enabled = false; // disable any weblogroutes
           }
       }
       Yii::app()->end();
   }
```

Appreciate any help on this

Comment: Oi.... fix to the problem is that the formated data must contain an id and text value pair... ie CustoemrCode must be evaled to id and Name must eval to text. Stupid, but it works.....

Answer (score 0):

i try.

change
 `'dataType' => 'jsonp' to 'dataType' => 'json'`

and check json format

https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/920